# Need a way to set vCenter Operations Manager 5.8.4 SSL via shell command

Tags: vmware

First......THIS IS NOT A REALIZE OPERATIONS MANAGER....it is vCenter, they are different

Our client purchased a new * ssl cert and wanted us to install it into their vCOP device. Easy peasy, took the PEM they provided, uploaded it, clicked install....everything broke

Turns out the client did not build their PEM file correctly and it broke all sorts of things.

When I log into the vcop/admin portal and login I am greeted with a "Repair Virtual Appliance" page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEHWo.png)

I have tried FQDNs and IPs of the required fields I have used the root and the administrator@vsphere.local accounts, it always fails. Interesting note, if I give it a bad password it says it can't connect. if I give it a good password it says the repair operation failed.

I can remote to the machine with winscp and putty. I was able to find some temp areas where the bad pem file was stored, and I found a second area where it looks like the pem was installed to. However replacing both pem files with the proper one does nothing. When going to the web gui it still shows the invalid cert that was uploaded and broke everything.

So for the past number of hours I have been pouring over documentation and processes for how to either copy a corrected pem into the correct area, or some sort of shell command to revert the installed SSL to a self signed cert so I can get back into the admin portal and upload the properly formed pem file.

TL;DR Does anyone know a command to reset the vCOP back to a self signed ssl cert, or where to put a pem in file structure to replace a bad pem?